# How to track source traffic from utm to Youtube video page?

Tags: google-analytics, youtube, qr-code, utm

UPD. I realised that I need to rephrase the question. So does anybody know how to track Youtube video views that come from a specific QR code? There may be different QR codes for the same video.

My ideas:

According to stackoverflow utm parameters don't work for youtube links. Theoretically I can create a page on my website that redirects to Youtube video page and put its link into QR code. Google Analytics will show stats for this page. But I can't track how long users watched the video because Youtube analytics shows breakdown of External traffic up to domain only and not for exact links. So not ideal and quite complicated with redirects.

Any other ideas? Thanks!

### ------

Hi.
We need to create a QR code for a paper leaflet with the link leading to Youtube video page. We are going to add utm source parameter to the link to see how many people will use this QR code.

My question is where I can see the stats on non-standard traffic sources for this Youtube video page? I don't see this option in Youtube itself and I've read that if I link Google analytics to my Youtube channel, it will show data for the channel page only and not for individual video pages. Is it true? How can I see the breakdown of 'Ex­tern­al' source in Youtube video page stats to see exact destinations the traffic comes from?

I'm in the process of setting up Google analytics for my channel and it doesn't work (it's a separate question) so I want to understand if it can help me with my problem at all.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

UTM parameters will only work to show you data coming to your website. Also, setting up Google Analytics for your channel will only make sense if the channel videos are embedded in a website, otherwise, you just need to use YouTube Analytics.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But is it possible to see traffic source for youtube video page? It should be a common thing, I think many people want to know where the traffic is coming from to watch their videos. Or is it impossible to track?

Comment: Hello, How about using this recipe. https://www.socialmediaexaminer.com/how-to-analyze-your-youtube-marketing-with-google-analytics/  . Please remember the bit at the end on UTM parameters

Comment: Yes, this is the first thing I did. The problem is this guide is from 2016 and now it doesn't work this way. First, GA stopped showing traffic for youtube video pages and left data on channel page only. And since the middle/end of last year the data stopped showing at all, at least for newly installed codes. I found dozens of forum posts and comments about it and in my account it doesn't work either. Just no data is coming in from Youtube to GA.

Comment: i am sorry that I have not found a solution that works. I will keep an eye out on this issue and if I find something out, will post it here.